Zipkin, micrometer log tracing not working
I have enabled log tracing through micrometer and zipkin. But i am not able to get span id and trace id in my requests.
Dependencies in pom.xml are as follows:
`    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>`

zipkin configuration in application.properties is as follows:

# zipkin configurations
management.tracing.enabled=true
management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://localhost:9411/zipkin/api/v2/spans
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0

I added the required dependency in pom.xml and properties in application.properties. Is there any other configuration or handling required to achieve the tracing of requests?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

More info about the environment also helps: I guess it is Spring Boot but the version is unknown.

I guess you mean "log correlation", if not, I'm not sure what "log tracing" is.
Try to use SLF4J and log something out in one of your Spring Boot controllers.
Alternatively, you can use this property to test:
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=DEBUG

If tracing information is not in these logs, you need to upgrade Boot to at least 3.2 but 3.3 is already out, I would use that instead.
If you don't want to upgrade, you need to set the logging.pattern.level property (see docs):
logging.pattern.level="%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"

